# Android Browser Plugin Development

Tags: android, android-ndk

i would like to develop a browser plugin for Android and have some questions:

1. Will it be usable at all android devices?
2. Is [this example](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/development.git;a=tree;f=samples/BrowserPlugin;h=1f803ad4df5c068089cd7f0ccb8981dccc1782f3;hb=HEAD) up-to-date?
3. I tried the example given above, but it fails because it doesn't find npapi.h and so on. How do i have to set up my environment (webkit?)

For clarification: I need to react to an object embedden in an html site similar like this

```
<object type="application/x-mytype" height=50 width=250 param name="param1" value="value1" />
...
</object>
```

read out the parameters and start an application with them

Comment: There are lots of android browsers. You have to tell us which one you want to create a plugin for. As far as I know, the default android browser doesn't have a way to make plugins.

Comment: Yes, should be for the default browser. I'd like to react on an object with a specific mime type, read out the parameters an initialize an application with them.

Comment: I've written a guide which I hope will be helpful, please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15244703/2138979

Comment: @Falmarri Are u sure that default android browser does not have a way to make plugins? that would be better if you provide any reasons or proof.