# Load NPAPI Plugin on Android device/emulator

Tags: android, c++, plugins, npapi

I compiled sample NPAPI Plugin which I got from this link http://code.google.com/p/npapi-sdk/

after compiling it using NDK, I got the .so file libs/armeabi/libBasicPlugin.so

after searching on Google I came across following suggestions:

1. put .so file in /data/data/com.android.browser/app_plugins/
2. put .so file in /data/data/com.android.browser/assets/plugins/

but none of that works on emulator (haven't tried on device)

I tried it on Gingerbread and ICS.

Comment: Shouldn't you get an APK out in the end and put that onto the device?

Comment: yes, so I figured that I needed to add JNI interface and built it again to get apk which works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Plugin for webkit can't work anymore. There's a test in the PluginManager.java file (framework/core/java/webkit something like that) and allows only the plugin of flash to be loaded (only when ro.secure = 1). If you want to load the plugin you have to root your device.